# How do I allow another attempt at an input

Tags: java, switch-statement

So I have this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test2{ 
  public void myScanner () {
    System.out.println("Do you want to have an adventure?");
    System.out.println("1 for yes, 2 for no");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);        
    String input = scanner.next();
    int answer = Integer.parseInt(input);
        switch (answer) {
          case 1: System.out.println("yes");
          break;

          case 2: System.out.println ("no");
          break;

          default: System.out.println("not valid answer"); 
        }
     }
 }
```

And what I'm trying to figure out is how to allow another attempt at answering the question after a wrong answer is given. So far, everything else works perfectly.

Comment: You need a loop of some kind

Comment: If you want _all_ invalid answers to take input again, you shouldn't call `Integer.parseInt` and you should change the switch cases to `"1"` and `"2"` (switching on `input`). Currently, if the user types `hello`, your code will throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke myScanner() function after default: statement

```
 default: System.out.println("not valid answer"); 
 myScanner();
```

Comment: Although this is a trivial example, using recursion here is setting yourself up for a potential stack overflow (given that you're at the mercy of what the user types in)

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a boolean variable called `validAnswer` before you ask for input from the user. Give it an initial value of `false`.

You can then wrap the section of your code that prompts for input from the user in a `while` block, like so:

```
while(!validAnswer) {
  String input = scanner.next();
  //etc, etc.
}
```

You then need to modify your switch statement so that if the input is valid, set `validAnswer` to true in addition to printing to the console - this should let you escape from the `while` loop but keep the loop going if the input is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

As you're learning: the basic way to do this is :

```
boolean exit;
    do{ 
      exit = true;
      System.out.println("Do you want to have an adventure?");
      System.out.println("1 for yes, 2 for no");
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
      String input = scanner.next();
      int answer = Integer.parseInt(input);
      switch (answer) {
        case 1: System.out.println("yes");
        break;

        case 2: System.out.println ("no");
        break;

        default: System.out.println("not valid answer"); 
        exit = false;
      }   
    } while(!exit);
```